# How to tell whether ant installed/what is $ command?

Tags: ant, installation

I'm trying to install ant on my computer per [this](http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/31930982/Getting-Started-with-PhoneGap-%28BlackBerry-Widgets%29#).

The instructions say to check whether ant is installed, type $ ant -v in a command window.

When I type that, I get this message: "$ is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

Does this mean that ant is not installed? Is $ a command that would work if ant were installed?

I can't find a computer command beginning with $ on the web.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect whether tomcat and ant are installed on linux machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14995936/how-to-detect-whether-tomcat-and-ant-are-installed-on-linux-machine)

Answer (score 11):

`$' just indicates that you should type what it says into a shell.

Just type:

```
ant -v
```

Omit the dollar sign.

Comment: If ant fails to run that doesn't prove that it isn't installed, it might be incorrectly configured, eg missing from path. I'm looking for a means to determine if the binaries are installed.

Answer (score 2):

The Unix command is `ant -version`

If Apache Ant is installed it will return:

> Apache Ant(TM) version {version-number} compiled on {date}

Answer (score 0):

$ is part of the shell prompt.  It is there to show you which lines are input and which are output.  Leave it out when entering the commands.

In the windows part, the prompt is "C:\path\to\working\dir>"

Answer (score 0):

$ is linux command prompt sign. For windows you can just ignore it

Answer (score 0):

ya $ is not recognized in win xp,

Is their any other method to know whether Ant is installed or not...
Like for [Java](http://javablogforbeginners.blogspot.com/) if you type java in cmd U will get few options....which tells that java is installed.