# How to detect whether tomcat and ant are installed on linux machine

Tags: linux, apache, tomcat, ant, version

I am trying to install `Tomcat` and `Ant` on my linux machine, but before installing them i just need to check whether they are already installed or not.

**Regarding tomcat**:

I googled a lot and searched on my machine in the following directories for tomcat

```
/usr/local/, /opt/, /usr/share/
```

but i din't find tomcat folder in any of the above path, whether it indicates that `tomcat` is not installed ? so actually

```
1. what is the path to `look/find` exactly to know/check whether tomcat is installed or not in 
   all linux machines
2. what will be the path the tomcat will be installed exactly after installation
3. How to find the version of tomcat on any linux machine (if tomcat already installed) 
4. Whether there are any commands to look for both whether `tomcat` installed and `ant` 
   installed
```

**Regarding Ant**:

I googled and got the below command due to which i got the below result after executing 
it

```
sh-4.2$ ant -v
```

**result**

```
sh-4.2$ ant -v
Apache Ant(TM) version 1.8.2 compiled on November 21 2011
Trying the default build file: build.xml
Buildfile: build.xml does not exist!
Build failed
```

so actually

```
1. Does the above result mean that `Ant` is installed ? or not ?
2. what is the path to `look/find` exactly to know/check whether ant is installed or not in 
   all linux machines
3. what will be the path the `ant` will be installed exactly after installation
4. How to find the version of `Ant` on any linux machine (if Ant already installed)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, you can check whether they are on the $PATH, if they are not on the $PATH, install one.

For ant:

`ant -v` stands for verbose, `ant -version` prints out its version.

```
   -help, -h
          print help on the command line options

   -projecthelp, -p
          gives information on possible targets for this project

   -version
          prints the version number and then exits ant

   -quiet, -q
          be extra quiet

   -verbose, -v
          be extra verbose

   -debug, -d
          print debugging information

   -emacs, -e
          produce logging information without adornments

   -logfile <file>, -l <file>
          use the given file to output log to

   -logger <classname>
          the class which is to perform logging

   -listener <classname>
          add an instance of the given class as a project listener

   -noinput
          do not allow interactive input

   -buildfile <file>, -file <file>, -f <file>
          use  the  given buildfile instead of the default build.xml file.
          This is the ant equivalent of Makefile

   -D<property>=<value>
          use value for the given property

   -keep-going, -k
          execute all targets that do not depend on failed target(s)

   -propertyfile <file>
          load all properties from file with -D properties  taking  prece-
          dence

   -inputhandler <class>
          the class which will handle input requests

   -find <file>, -s <file>
          (s)earch  for  buildfile  towards the root of the filesystem and
          use it

   -nice number
          A niceness value for the main thread: 1 (lowest)  to  10  (high-
          est); 5 is the default

   -nouserlib
          Run ant without using the jar files from ${user.home}/.ant/lib

   -noclasspath
          Run ant without using CLASSPATH

   -autoproxy
          Java 1.5+ : use the OS proxies

   -main <class>
          override ant's normal entry point
```

For tomcat:

if tomcat/bin is on the $PATH variable, version.sh will print out the version.

Comment: For Ant  : Its ok to find the version of ant, but where/what will be the path that ant will be installed on linux ?

Comment: For tomcat: Here what is $PATH variable? How to find it ? i can't find any tomcat folder anywhere on the system ? and where will be actual path that tomcat will be isntalled ?

Comment: because first i will check whether tomcat is in that path and after that i will run version.sh ...... because before not knowing where tomcat will be located/installed how can we go in to that folder and execute version.sh ?

Comment: use 'which ant' to find where the ant is. You can use ant without using /usr/../../ant because it is on the $PATH variable. Use 'echo $PATH' to have a look.

Comment: If it is not on the $PATH variable. Then you can install it. It has very little side effect.

Comment: actually i have mentioned in the the above question that i have checked in some folders(/usr/local/,/opt/,/usr/share/) for tomcat ? so for sure after tomcat installed it will locate in one of those paths/folders ?

Comment: Why you need to confirm these folders, you can install it to any folder you want. Generally I refer to tomcat through a softlink at /usr/local/tomcat, which would allow me to upgrade versions by simply installing a new version in another folder and changing the softlink.

Comment: k i am happy about ant, i can able to find tha path and version like "which ant", "ant -version", but what about 'tomcat' ? when i executed echo $PATH the result is /usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/lib64/ccache:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

Comment: actually i am developing a server readiness script in python that will check for all availability of softwares like Tomcat, ant, Apache, Java , etc., before installing java, so i am trying to check the availability of tomcat and ant dynamically on all linux machines.

Comment: Then unfortuately, there is no official folder for tomcat. Also there is no for ant. There might be several versions of ant installed. After 'which ant', you got the directory where ant locates in, it is on the $PATH variable, if you modify the dir out of the variable, you can get nothing when executing 'ant'. However, people can still use ant by /antdir/ant. So if you want to check the availability of these tools. You really have to search the entire filesystem.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24874/discussion-between-shiva-krishna-and-jermaine-xu)

Comment: can we please carry on this here http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24874/discussion-between-shiva-krishna-and-jermaine-xu

Answer (score 0):

For linux ubuntu 18.04:

```
Go to terminal and command:$ sudo systemctl status tomcat
```

This command also show is tomcat running or not (if already installed)